# Iterate in nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of objects here that I need to repeat with a list and their titles.
The expected output is:

#1 List title

- Airports
- Aircrafts

#2 List title

- Pilots
- Business

`key` is returning the list title however I don't figure out how to iterate through title and link? Any help much appreciated.

```
const obj = { 
    '#1 List title': [{
        title: 'Airports', 
        link: 'airports'
      },
      {
        title: 'Aircrafts', 
        link: 'aircrafts'
      },
    ],
    '#2 List title': [{
        title: 'Pilots', 
        link: 'pilots'
      },
      {
        title: 'Business', 
        link: 'business'
      },
    ],    
  };

  const listItem =  Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => 
    <div key={key}>
      <div>{key}</div>
      <div>
        <div href={`/${val.link}/`}>
          {val.title}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: `val` is an array. You need to map over it again to access `.link` and `.title` on the individual elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Object.keys()

```
const listItem =  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => 
    <div key={key}>
      <div>{key}</div>
      <div>
        {obj[key].map(el =>
        <div href={`/${el.link}/`}>
          {el.title}
        </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.map(key=>obj[key].map(val=>
<div key={key}>
  <div>{key}</div>
  <div>
    <div href={`/${val.link}/`}>
      {val.title}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
));
```